# Simple java chat app reading image

Tags: java, client-server, java-io, javax.imageio

I tried to create a Chat application , but faced two problems, the first when sending the emoticon it is appear as follows
[image]

And This is my code (sending emoticon)

```
private void sendEmotion(ImageIcon emoticon, URL url) {

    try {
        Image image = emotion.getImage();
        listModel.addElement(emoticon);
        jList2.setModel(listModel);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(url.toURI()));
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", s.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

reading text and emoticon

```
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while (true) {
            // To read text
            String st = br.readLine();
            listModel.addElement(st);
           jList1.setModel(listModel);
            //to read imge
              BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());

              ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("e:/image.png"));
              listModel.addElement(image);
              jList1.setModel(listModel);

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The second problem , when sending text and image from server to client, The client  can't read both (text or image not both)

Comment: The word is not 'emotions' but 'emoticons'.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you really need to send the image itself in case of emoticons. Those emoticons have a String representation such as `:)` or `:(`. So when sending an emoticon you can include the appropriate String and on the receiver´s side just match that string to the necessary emoticon and display the locally saved image.

Comment: thnx but What if it were any other image not emotions

Comment: i think opening a secondary connection is more appropriate because sending images/files might take long so it shouldnt delay the ongoing conversation

Answer (score 0):

Answering your query to send emoticons : You have same set of smiley at all clients, i would say maintain an Enum for smileys, pass the identifier of the selected smiley instead of image and render accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing buffered and unbuffered streams on the same underlying `Socket` cannot possibly work. The buffered stream, in this case a `BufferedReader`, will 'steal' data from the unbuffered stream via which you're trying to read the image. Use the same stream for both, somehow, e.g. via `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` and `DataInputStream.readUTF().`